# Showing $\left\{ \frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^k} \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\rightarrow 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to prove:

$$\left\{ \frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^k} \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\rightarrow 1$$

I found a proof applying [Stolz criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) but I need to use the fact that:

$$\left\{\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\right\}\text{ is bounded}\tag{$\ast$}$$

I would like to calculate this limit **without** using $(\ast)$ and preferably using basic limit criterion and properties.

(*Sorry about mispellings or mistakes, English is not my native language.*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously
$$\frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^k \geq 1,$$
while:
$$\frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^k\leq \frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^k\leq\frac{1}{n^n}\cdot\frac{n^n}{1-\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{n}{n-1}.$$

Comment: Very simple proof, thanks!

Comment: (Morally) shouldn't there be an equality sign in the second step?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: yes, sure. Now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$n^n\le\sum_{k=1}^nk^k\le n^n+(n-1)^{n-1}+(n-2)(n-2)^{n-2}$$